# Localhost throwing invalid response after running http-server for Angular PWA

Tags: angular, angular-pwa

I have installed PWA to my Angular application by `ng add @angular/pwa` and followed the all necessary steps.

To run PWA locally I have installed `http-server` globally by `npm i -g http-server`

After building production by `ng build --prod`, I ran `http-server -o` from `dist` folder but localhost is not working and throwing invalid response.

I have tried with different ports by `http-server -p 5000` but it's not working.

Comment: Can you post the error msg

Comment: This page isn’t working 

127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.

ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

This is the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to execute "http-server -o" command from dist/  and not from dist.

Also as mentioned in https://github.com/http-party/http-server/issues/525 I had to access using http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html instead of http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 0):

you will see something like this

```
"http-server -a localhost -p 5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by navigating to: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to http-server 0.9.0 fixed it for me.

```
npm install -g http-server@0.9.0
```